# Is it possible to set proxy for APT while using graphical Ubiquity-based desktop ISO installer?

Tags: networking, system-installation, proxy, ubuntu-mate, ubiquity

For some of the Ubuntu installations I use netboot mini.iso from http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/ . This installation method includes the step of configuring proxy. It is very useful for me as I have Squid-Deb-Proxy configured in my network, so I can lower traffic usage by using it.

But I do not see such an option in Ubuntu Desktop graphical installers, for example for Ubuntu MATE. They use Ubiquity as a common. Is it possible to set APT proxy during installation for such installers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [source code of Ubiquity](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/tree/ubiquity/components/apt_setup.py?h=applied/ubuntu/eoan) it obtains the proxy settings from two sources:

1. installer preseed file (not our case)
2. proxy configuration of current user (namely GSettings path `org.gnome.system.proxy`)

For Ubuntu MATE desktop installer one can use the following method:

1. Boot system in *Try Ubuntu MATE without installation*
2. Launch *Network Proxy* application from dash or by using `mate-network-properties`
3. Specify needed HTTP proxy:

   > [o] **Manual proxy configuration**
   >   HTTP proxy: [192.168.12.34] Port: [8000]

   and click *Close*.

   Note: this step may be done from terminal by using the following commands

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode "'manual'"
   gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http host "192.168.12.34"
   gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http port "8000"
   ```
4. Launch Ubiquity installer by clicking on its *Install Ubuntu MATE ...* icon on desktop.
5. Proceed with installation as usual and wait to finish.

As the result you will get this proxy saved in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` as *mini.iso* does:

> ```
> $ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf
> Acquire::http::Proxy "http://192.168.12.34:8000";
> ```

For the more universal solution it is recommended to remove this file and use special avahi-based package `sudo apt-get install squid-deb-proxy-client` to access it by hostname.

---

Note: this method may be adapted for other Ubuntu flavors, but I did not tested them.