# install ubuntu desktop using a proxy server?

Tags: system-installation, proxy, 20.04

Is there some way, when installing Ubuntu-20.04 Desktop, to tell the installer to use a proxy server?  I didn't see any option for that (unlike when installing Ubuntu Server) and trying to google an answer seems impossible because the results are all about setting a proxy after install.

I have a slow, metered internet connection so I want to install though my caching proxy so that any subsequent installs will not have to re-download hundreds of megabytes of packages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to set proxy for APT while using graphical Ubiquity-based desktop ISO installer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204128/is-it-possible-to-set-proxy-for-apt-while-using-graphical-ubiquity-based-desktop) - I have answer for MATE here, but you can get the idea. Tested this method recently on regular Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with GNOME.

Comment: Thanks, but sadly those instructions didn't work.  The installer seems to run four steps based of the progress messages:
1) copying files (these I think came from the install iso);
2) installing system (no file copying); 
3) retrieving file n of 111 (these downloads went though proxy server);
4) downloading packages (these didn't use proxy.  I waited ~10 minutes while internet link ran at full speed and then aborted the install. :-(